# Windows Defender Antivirus API

Tags: c, windows, winapi, antivirus, windows-defender

Reading the documentation of the windows defender API, for example in `MpManagerOpen` Function:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn920115(v=vs.85).aspx

I see that the required include file is `MpClient.h`. However I couldn't find it anywhere. Does anyone know where can I find this file, or simply how to use the API without it (without copying the prototypes and structs to my own code), in a C program?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the Windows 8 SDK?

Comment: Yes I have the SDK (even windows 10)

Comment: You have two options: you can either copy the prototypes or you find the files that include them. I copied them from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dn920144(v=vs.85).aspx) and it seems to work. I wouldn't recommend using it though, as important parts of the API are obviously undocumented.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for that header as well. I found a copy here:
https://github.com/hfiref0x/UACME/blob/master/Source/Shared/mpclient.h

Comment: Note that URL is broken now. I found another one which currently works: https://github.com/UldisRinkevichs/libmpclient/blob/48585c8916864c13113b3af166b2718f7e0d4464/Source/libmpclient/libmpclient/MpClient.h#L11